# CSS styling elements while keeping them centered

Tags: html, css

I have this:

`span:`

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

and the container

`li:`

```
height: 20vh;
display: table;
text-align: center;
```

The span is centered horizontally, but when the element is `<span>hello<br>world</span>` I'd like the Hello and world to both be aligned on the left while centered in their parent `li`.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: can you show a example how you want

Answer (score 2):

just add `text-align: left` to `span`:

```
li{
   height: 20vh;
   display: table;
   text-align: center;
}

span{
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
   text-align: left;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zL3qjtnw/)

Comment: It seems to not work without Hello string outside of span - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zL3qjtnw/1/). Span is filling whole li and content is not centered.

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
 text-align: left;
```

Add this style span or li as u need